# Java Virtual Machine Specification (JVMS): Bug in "5.4.5 Method overriding"

Tags: jvm, bytecode

I filed the following bug on September 28th, 2009. Sadly, I still did not get any response and the final version of the specification still is incorrect. Is this really a bug? If not, why not? If yes, what should I do?

The section that contains the bug is `5.4.5` (Method overriding): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.5 in combination with the description of the `INVOKEVIRTUAL` opcode: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual

According to 5.4.5 `m1` can override `m2` even if `m1` is private. This can happen if creating `.class` files manually or combining the `.class` from two compilations.

In my example I have classes `A` and `B` with `B extends A`. I compiled these classes so that `A` contains a `public` method named `f` and `B` contains a `private` method, also named `f` (by first declaring both methods `public`, compiling, copying `A.class` to a safe place, removing the declaration of `f` in `A` and changing to `private` in `B`, then compile `B` and using the saved version of `A.class`).

When now running this, my current Oracle JVM outputs `A` (meaning the method `f` in `A` is invoked). According to the specification, `B` should be the output (meaning the method `f` in `B` should be invoked).

EDIT: Actually, `B.f` should be resolved. Invocation may fail because of access right checks for the resolved method, if the caller is not `B`. However, I believe the method resolution part is wrong.

I think that the definition in `5.4.5` should check the access rights of `m1`, not only `m2`.

```
public class A {
  public void f();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String A
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}

public class B extends A {
  private void f();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String B
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

Thanks,
Carsten

Comment: The JVM doesn't always follow the specification exactly. I guess this is another example.

Comment: So the specification is "correct" in the sense that `B.f` should be invoked? I don't really care about other JVMs, because I implemented my own (abstract) JVM - but for that I need a bug-free specification.

Comment: Personally, I'd just try to emulate the Hotspot JVM where feasible, since it's a defacto standard so emulating it will lead to better compatibility with broken programs.

Comment: Well, I'm working on a tool that proves (non)termination. Doing nasty tricks like ignoring the spec is not a good idea :)

Comment: That's an undecidable problem, and it gets even worse if you want to consider reflection or JNI.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that in the last four years of pursuing my PhD.

Comment: Who is invoking the method? If it’s a class other than `B` it should not output `B` but rather throw an error. The method resolution should find `B.f()` but then, according to `5.4.3.3`: “Otherwise, if method lookup succeeds but the referenced method is not accessible (§5.4.4) to D, method resolution throws an `IllegalAccessError`” whereas §5.4.4 clearly says that `private` methods are accessible to the same class only. Since invoking a `private` method by any other means than an `invokespecial` instruction I would rather expect a clarification in a newer specification than a JVM change.

Comment: OK, you may be right. However, I expect method resolution to not find `B.f` in the first place.

Comment: @C-Otto: I wouldn’t expect it too. I just was referring to the “if taken word by word” scenario. Now that the Java 8 JVM spec contains the expected clarification that line of thought is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has been addressed, finally. The [current version of the Java 8 JVM specification](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-pfd-spec/java-se-8-jvms-pfd-diffs.pdf) contains the required clarification:

> #### 5.4.5 Overriding
>
> An instance method m<sub>C</sub> declared in class C overrides another instance method m<sub>A</sub>
>   declared in class A iff either m<sub>C</sub> is the same as m<sub>A</sub>, or all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - m<sub>C</sub> has the same name and descriptor as m<sub>A</sub>.
> - **m<sub>C</sub> is not marked ACC_PRIVATE.**
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is marked ACC_PUBLIC; or is marked ACC_PROTECTED; or is marked neither
>       ACC_PUBLIC nor ACC_PROTECTED nor ACC_PRIVATE and A belongs to the same
>       run-time package as C.
>   - m<sub>C</sub> overrides a method m' (m' distinct from m<sub>C</sub> and m<sub>A</sub>) such that m' overrides m<sub>A</sub>.

There is another addition in §4.10.1.5 “Type Checking Abstract and Native Methods”:

> private methods and static methods are orthogonal to dynamic method dispatch,
>   so they never override other methods (§5.4.5).

Less than five years for a fix, that’s fast compared to some other issues…